# Writing extracted information from python dictionary to a file

Tags: python, linux, linux-mint

I have the following code:

```
import os
import sys
import re
import glob
import datetime
import subprocess
from functions import *

event_dict = {1102: 0, 4611: 0,  4624: 0, 4634: 0, 4648: 0, 4661: 0, 4662: 0, 4663: 0, 4672: 0, 4673: 0, 4688: 0, 4698: 0, 4699: 0, 4702: 0, 4703: 0, 4719: 0, 4732: 0, 4738: 0, 4742: 0, 4776: 0, 4798: 0, 4799: 0, 4985: 0, 5136: 0, 5140: 0, 5142: 0, 5156: 0, 5158: 0}

event_IDs = [1102,4611,4624,4634,4648,4661,4662,4663,4672,4673,4688,4698,4699,4702,4703,4719,4732,4738,4742,4776,4798,4799,4985,5136,5140,5142,5156,5158]
iterations = 0


def finding_matched_events():

        with open('/home/user/CI5235_K1715142_Gary/CI5235_Logs/analyse_log_28_Feb_2021_11:22:05.txt', 'r') as logfile:
                for line in logfile:
                        if 'Matched' in line:

                                events = re.findall('\d+', line)

                                event_dict[int(events[0])] = event_dict[int(events[0])] + 1



 finding_matched_events()
   print(event_dict)

def log_output():   #Function to Print out event ID and count information and save to log file

        with open('/home/user/CI5235_K1715142_Gary/CI5235_Logs/visdata_log_' + timeStamp + '.txt', 'a') as f :
```

The above code returns: `{1102: 15, 4611: 2, 4624: 46, 4634: 1, 4648: 6, 4661: 19, 4662: 33, 4663: 114, 4672: 12, 4673: 2, 4688: 35, 4698: 2, 4699: 2, 4702: 4, 4703: 1, 4719: 8, 4732: 2, 4738: 5, 4742: 4, 4776: 7, 4798: 2, 4799: 1, 4985: 2, 5136: 42, 5140: 6, 5142: 1, 5156: 92, 5158: 14}` When calling the function and priting event_dict.

****I'm then writing another function log_ouput, in which I'm using that extracted data and trying to see if I can get that data to be displayed in a certain way but I'm not too sure how to achieve it. How would I be able to write that extracted data above in a way that looks like:**

Event ID:1102
Event Count:15

Event ID:4611
Event Count:2

Event ID:4624
Event Count:46

Event ID:4634
Event Count:1

Event ID:4648
Event Count:6

etc....

I'm fairly new to coding, using Python3, Linux Mint and VisualStudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code will write out your dictionary:

```
event_dict = {1102: 15, 4611: 2, 4624: 46, 4634: 1,
              4648: 6, 4661: 19, 4662: 33, 4663: 114,
              4672: 12, 4673: 2, 4688: 35, 4698: 2,
              4699: 2, 4702: 4, 4703: 1, 4719: 8,
              4732: 2, 4738: 5, 4742: 4, 4776: 7,
              4798: 2, 4799: 1, 4985: 2, 5136: 42,
              5140: 6, 5142: 1, 5156: 92, 5158: 14}

fbase = '/home/user/CI5235_K1715142_Gary/CI5235_Logs/visdata_log_'
with open(fbase + timeStamp + '.txt', 'a') as f:
    for k,v in event_dict.items():
        print(f"Event ID:{k} Event Count:{v}", file=f)
# Event ID:1102 Event Count:15
# Event ID:4611 Event Count:2
# ...
```

Comment: Hi! Thank you for this! This does the exact what I need although it doesn't print it to a logfile like with mentioned in the main question with the log_output function. Would it be easy to modify it so that that print appears in the logfile instead? So it doesn't print on screen?

Comment: Yes, I can do that.

Comment: Thank you so much! I'm fairly new to programming so it's so welcoming to see such great people on this community. I hope to learn from solutions like yours

Comment: If you like the answer, please accept it as the answer, and give it an upvote. If you like other answers, too, then give those answers an upvote.

Comment: Accepted as answer. Have a great day!

Answer (score 2):

```
 with open('/home/user/CI5235_K1715142_Gary/CI5235_Logs/visdata_log_' + timeStamp + '.txt', 'a') as f :
    for key in event_dict:
        f.write("Event ID:{} Event Count:{}".format(key, event_dict[key]))
```

Comment: Thank you! This works great, although in the logfile it comes out like: Event ID:1102 Event Count:15Event ID:4611 Event Count:2Event ID:4624 instead of having them printed line by line like in the example above so that they print on top of each other and below each other instead of one long line. If that makes sense? Would I be able to easily modify the code to sort this?

Comment: This should work:
`f.write("Event ID:{} Event Count:{}\n".format(key, event_dict[key]))`